# Why delegate method is not called - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I have an AudioRecorder class for recording audio, and I have the following code:

```
_recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];
        
if (_recorder && [_recorder prepareToRecord]) {
    [_recorder recordForDuration:10.0]; // Record for 10 seconds
    [_recorder setDelegate:self];
    [_recorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];
}
```

So, here `self` is the `AudioRecorder` class which is declare as:

```
@interface AudioRecorder : NSObject <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>
    
@property AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
@property AVAudioSession *session;

@end
```

Then I have this callback method that **should** (but is not) called after the 10 seconds registration:

```
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag {}
```

Why is this not called after the 10 sec registration?

Comment: Is `AudioRecorder` instance "still" alive? Not just a local variable?

Comment: I call that from an external class with: `AudioRecorder *audioRecorder = [AudioRecorder new];` I think it's ok

Comment: I can't understand if `audioRecordDidFinishRecording` is automatically triggered after the `recordForDuration`. Should be right?

Comment: I guess, `audioRecorder`. should be a property of that class. Else, if it's local, it will be released as soon as the scopes end (more or less on next closing `}`, and then, `_recorder` will be released too, before the delegate method gets called.

Comment: You are right!!! Thank you, if u post the answer I accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common reason which make delegate methods not being called.

The first one is not setting the `delegate` property or implementing a wrong method (ie, typo on the method).
Which is not the case here.

The second one, is that the object is released (from memory) too soon.
In other words, the delegate method will be called later (here ~10 seconds after), and `delegate` properties are almost always `weak`ly reference to avoid memory issue (cycle), when the object need to call its delegate method, the object doesn't exist anymore. That's your issue.
The small difference here, it's that's the parent of the delegate that is released too soon.
Because `_recorder` is a property of `AudioRecorder`, so as long as the `AudioRecorder` instance exists, it will still be here and let the delegate method be called.
But, the `AudioRecorder` is a local variable, so it will cease to exists after its scope (~after the next closing `}`).

So you need to make `AudioRecorder` a property of the object holding it.

Comment: Just coming with a new questions... Please have a look at it :D